# Typescript - Expanding and Collapsing a bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

using typescript How to expand and collapse bootstrap panel try below code but no success.
I want open in typescript.

**Code-1**

```
<div class="panel panel-white">
    <div class="panel-heading removeColor" id="passins_heading">
            <h6 class="panel-title">
                <button class="collapsed" id="openPassion" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Passions" >Click Here</button>
            </h6>           
    </div>

    <div id="Passions" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">                

                    Content -1              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Cord-2**

```
<div class="panel panel-white">
        <div class="panel-heading removeColor" id="passins_heading">
                <h6 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Passions"> Click Here </a>
                </h6>           
        </div>

        <div id="Passions" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        Content -1                                              

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
import * as JQuery from 'jquery';


setTimeout(() => {
                JQuery( '#openPassion' ).toggle();
            }, 5000 );
```

how Expanding and Collapsing in a component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution can be something like this:

First, create a reference on your button:
`<button #myButton ...`

Then in your code, you can use the ViewChild decorator to find it:

```
  @ViewChild('myButton')
  private myButtonRef: ElementRef;
```

and then, you can "click" it in the control class:

```
setTimeout(() => {
            this.myButtonRef.nativeElement.click();
        }, 1000 );  }
```

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jEki4I2sE9JI1QUBnI9b) here.

Comment: this way, you don't need to use jquery either.